# When I am trying to run bash script on android shell I am getting syntax error

Tags: android, bash

I changed the shell of android by pushing a complied binary of bash(because by default android shell is sh), even then syntax error remains.

I invoked the script file as below:

```
sh Cstates.sh
```

This is my code:

```
declare -A stateMap
for (( y=0; y<`ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle |grep ^state[0-9]| wc -l`; y++ ))
do 
   key=`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state$y/name | sed 's/ //g'| sed 's/ *$//'`
   stateMap[$key]="state$y"
   if [[ $key != "POLL" ]]
   then
     possibleStates[$y]=$key
   fi
done
```

The error I get is:

```
Cstates.sh[7]: syntax error: '((' unexpected
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you write and include a three line script that reproduces the problem, along with the command line you used to run the script and the output you got? Please make sure to copy-paste it and don't type it from memory.

Comment: Cstates.sh[7]: syntax error: '((' unexpected

Comment: I don't know which cstates.sh has unexpected syntax. Something like https://gist.github.com/bdha/2024575 ? Please edit your question and post the Cstates.sh file.

Comment: `declare -A stateMap
for (( y=0; y<`ls /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle |grep ^state[0-9]| wc -l`; y++ ))
do
  key=`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpuidle/state$y/name | sed 's/ //g'| sed 's/ *$//'`
  stateMap[$key]="state$y"
  if [[ $key != "POLL" ]]
  then
    possibleStates[$y]=$key
  fi
done`

Comment: @WalterA i have included the code, in my comment above

Comment: @KarthikChilukuri I edited your question and added your code to it. Can you please edit your own question and add the command line you use to execute the script? Please also make sure to include the entire script and not just the part where you think the problem is: right now your error message seems to say line 7, but the only line with `((` on it is line 2.

Comment: @thatotherguy I know its annoying but I cannot include whole code :( , restricted by employer. This code is working perfectly on ubuntu (14.04,12.04) but not on android shell. I thank you for editing the question

Comment: @KarthikChilukuri Thanks for including invocation, that's the problem (see posted answer). In the future, you can both make the question better and avoid posting employer code by making a small test case and running that instead. In this case I think `for ((i=0; i<1; i++)); do echo hello; done`  would have been enough to  show the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you run the script:

```
sh Cstates.sh
```

This runs the script with `sh`, which does not support the features you want.

To instead run the script with bash, use:

```
/path/to/bash Cstates.sh
```

You can do the same thing by adding `#!/path/to/bash` as line number 1, and running `./Cstates.sh` (after granting permissions with `chmod +x file`)

Comment: ./Cstates.sh gives me permission denied error.


   bash Cstates.sh gives me bash :command not found.

Comment: Thanks for the update. But bash is not present in the android by default sh is the shell for android, I changed the default shell to bash by pushing the binaries of bash  [I followed these instructions](http://roycormier.net/2010/11/03/how-to-cross-compile-bash-for-android/)  still can't make it work.

Comment: @KarthikChilukuri If you followed that guide, `/path/to/bash` would be `/system/xbin/bash`. What happens when you run `/system/xbin/bash Cstates.sh`?